# How to update a third table with the result of a select inner join of another two tables

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have an access data base with three tables named DD, Export , and RPL

I have the result of a inner join betweent EXPORT AND DD which is working fine

Now with those results I want to update a third table RPL which is currently empty but has those fields to be populate for example RPL.[Hotel ID] should be the Hotel ID that results from the query below

```
SELECT Export.[Hotel ID], Export.[Property Name], Export.[Room Type ID] AS
[Parent Room Type ID], Export.[Room Type Code] AS [Parent Room Type Code],
Export.[Rate Plan ID] AS [Parent Rate Plan ID], Export.[Expedia Collect Rate 
Plan Code] AS [Parent Rate Plan Code EC], Export.[Hotel Collect Rate Plan 
Code] AS [Parent Rate Plan Code HC], Export.[Rate Plan Name] AS [Parent Rate
Plan Name]
INTO RPL
FROM Export INNER JOIN DD ON Export.ExKey = DD.DDKey;
```

The previous query copies the result into a new table, i want to use the one that exists already
Any help it is appreciated it

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your example is not clear, I will write a simpler one to clarify how to update a table use the data joined by other tables,
now there are three tables `ATable,BTable,CTable`, the colums of `ATable` is `id,value1,value2`, the columns of `BTable` is `id,value1`, the colums of `CTable` is `id,value2`,
now we will update ATable by use the data joined by the B and C, the SQL is like below:

```
update ATable a set value1 = t.value1, value2 = t.value2 
from (
  select
      b.id,
      b.value1,
      c.value2
  from
      BTable b
  join
      CTable c on b.id = c.id
) t where a.id = t.id
```

Comment: THank you , this helps. I apologize for the lack of clarity